# How to get back MacOS Ventura language change selector?(on MacOS Sonoma curently)

Tags: macos, language, sonoma

I`ve just updated to Sonoma and like it in general, but language selector is slow, unresponsive and cringe to me. Occasionally I trigger old one which I like much more.

Was anyone able to get back the old language selector animation on Sonoma?

Or at least turn off this new off))

Comment: Quite a few complaints about this in the Apple Support Communities, but no fix so far other than to ask Apple to revert to the old way via http://www.apple.com/feedback

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466101/removing-language-icon-from-input-fields-after-upgrading-to-macos-sonoma [Can't test, don't have Sonoma yet.]

Comment: Yes, this it! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am actually working on a solution and trying to recreate the old menu. I don't like the new one either.

See [lingoswitch](https://github.com/mcjkula/lingoswitch).

Comment: See also  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/465318/can-i-erase-the-keyboard-icon-that-appears-whenever-i-switch-the-input-keyboard

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
defaults write kCFPreferencesAnyApplication TSMLanguageIndicatorEnabled 0
```

As per https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250007827
Works miracles, no additional soft needed