# Can I erase the keyboard icon that appears whenever I switch the input keyboard on macOS Sonoma?

Tags: macos, keyboard, sonoma

I just upgraded to macOS 14.0 Sonoma, and found that whenever I switch my input keyboard, there appears a blue icon indicating which source I'm now using. This is quite annoying and I would rather erase it, since I know which source I'm using and there is an indicator on the menu bar.

Is it possible to disable it?

Comment: The solution was initially proposed in the thread [Disable macOS Sonoma Text Insertion Point (Cursor) / Caps-lock Indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77248249/1319821)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help fix the problem:

https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250007827

Comment: Hate to be the one to mention this Tom, but we do like link-rot-proof answers ;)) I know it's your own link, but just in case...