# Weird blue button for changing language suddenly appeared - What is it, and can I remove it?

Tags: sonoma

After updating to the latest version of macOS (Sonoma 14.1), I've noticed a strange blue button appearing every time I type. It acts as a shortcut to switch between languages. It's horrible, and I can't figure out which application added it, nor how to uninstall it.

Any ideas?

[image: The Blue button in action]

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/465318/can-i-erase-the-keyboard-icon-that-appears-whenever-i-switch-the-input-keyboard