# Removing language icon from input fields after upgrading to macOS Sonoma

Tags: macos, internationalization, sonoma

After upgrading my operating system from macOS Ventura to macOS Sonoma, I've noticed that now when I change the input language, an icon indicating the current language appears in the input fields. This was not the case before, and it has started to bother me.

Is there is a way to disable this language icon from appearing in the input fields in macOS Sonoma?

[image: Screenshot of the cursor in an input field showing a blue oval with the letter 'A']

[image: Screenshot of the cursor in an input field showing a blue oval with the letters 'py']

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Sonoma: any way to disable input source switch popup?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255161577?answerId=259780226022#259780226022) in Apple's Support Communities, you should be able to do this from Terminal via

`defaults write kCFPreferencesAnyApplication TSMLanguageIndicatorEnabled 0`

After that, restart your computer.